# Finding the minimum date value from a list of dates

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-objects

This will give me a list of my Start Dates: ( they are stored as **STRING** )

```
var startDate = myValues.Select(t => t.StartDate).ToList();
```

I only need it to choose the earliest date value from it. And if it is an empty string then that is also the winner, if no empty string then just see which one is really earliest.

Is there a way I can use `LINQ` and **combine** this part with the part I have above to find it on one go? Instead of writing more logic separately to find the min date from that list?

Comment: If you know they can be parsed to a `DateTime`, you could use the static `Parse` method to convert each item to a `DateTime` and then select the `Min` value: `myValues.Min(t => DateTime.Parse(t));`

Comment: I don't think that DateTime.Parse will work for empty strings? You might have to pass a custom comparer to the Min method which checks if the string is null/empty and otherwise it calls the DateTime.Parse method

Comment: A new DateTime will give minimum Date (1/1/01).  So try following : DateTime startDate = myValues.Select(t => (t.StartDate == string.Empty) ? new DateTime() : DateTime.Parse(t.StartDate)).Min(t => t.StartDate);

Comment: What if the values are not empty or valid `DateTime` objects? Do you just want to select the first one, return null, or throw an exception (or something else)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
string winner = myValues.Select(t => t.StartDate)
    .Select(s => new{ str = s, date = DateTime.TryParse(s, out DateTime dt) ? dt : new DateTime?() })
    .OrderByDescending(x => String.IsNullOrEmpty(x.str))
    .ThenByDescending(x => x.date.HasValue)
    .ThenBy(x => x.date.GetValueOrDefault())
    .Select(x => x.str)
    .First();
```

Comment: If the string is either empty or a valid string then a simple Min<long> would also work and in the Min check for a empty/null string return DateTime.MinValue.Ticks otherwise return DateTime.Parse(string).Ticks

Comment: I think you're missing `.StartDate` in a few places...`TryParse` takes a `string` as the first argument (as does `IsNullOrEmpty`), and the `Select` should select a `string`.

Comment: @RufusL you're right :) of course he needs to select the SartDate property first

Answer (score 0):

this may help you

```
var result = myValues?.Where(t=>!string.IsNullOrEmpty(t.StartDate))?.
  Select(t => { DateTime.TryParse(t.StartDate, out DateTime date); return date;})?.
  Min();
```